# Value minus sum of precedent rows values SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table which looks like this:

```
+---------+--------+-------+
|categ    |decrea  |lost   |
|---------|--------|-------+
|A        |1500    |20     |
|B        |1500    |40     |
|C        |1500    |60     |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

And I want to change the decrea values so that each value is equal to decrea minus the accumulated losses. So the result would look like :

```
+---------+---------------+-------+
|categ    |decrea         |lost   |
|---------|---------------|-------+
|A        |1500-20        |20     |
|B        |1500-(20+40)   |40     |
|C        |1500-(20+40+60)|60     |
+---------+--------+------+-------+
```

Anay help please ?

Comment: Accumulated according to what? Any timestamp or?

Comment: MS SQL or MySQL or any other SERVER?

Comment: @jarlh according to row order (index)

Comment: @DineshDB I'm using periscope data

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using Amazon Redshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below correlated query

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(categ varchar(1),decra INT, lost int)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES('A',1500,20)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES('B',1500,40)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES('C',1500,60)

SELECT *,    
    decra -
        (SELECT SUM(t2.lost) FROM @Table t2 WHERE t2.categ <= t1.categ) AS decra,
    lost
FROM @Table t1;
```

Comment: I tried that and get : `ERROR: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error`

Comment: This is a copy of my answer.  Which doesn't work anyway because Redshift doesn't support correlated subqueries in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a self join approach:

```
SELECT
    t1.categ,
    t1.decrea - SUM(t2.lost) AS decrea,
    t1.lost
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.categ >= t2.categ
GROUP BY
    t1.categ, t1.decrea, t1.lost
ORDER BY
    t1.categ;

Results:
  categ decrea lost
1 A     1480   20
2 B     1440   40
3 C     1380   60
```

### Demo

Comment: I tried that and get : 
`ERROR: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error`

Comment: @abdelkarim Another option here uses a self join, q.v. my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(categ varchar(1),decra INT, lost int)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES('A',1500,20)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES('B',1500,40)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES('C',1500,60)

SELECT *
    ,decra-SUM(lost) OVER(ORDER BY categ) Accumulated
FROM @Table
```

**OutPut**:

```
categ   decra   lost    Accumulated
A       1500    20      1480
B       1500    40      1440
C       1500    60      1380
```

Comment: the following error have been raised `ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause`